# Wolfram Alpha - limiting the input X set to prime integer numbers

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I was curious if I can get wolfram alpha to calculate for me the values of Y, but using only the prime integer values of X .

Currently I have the following:

`solve y=x+(30/x)+1 over the integers`

I would like to do something like this:

`solve y=x+(30/x)+1 over the prime integers`

OR

`solve y=x+(30/x)+1 over the prime numbers`

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3Dx%2B(30%2Fx)%2B1+over+the+integers

So far I am not getting the response I want... which is X=3, and Y=14.

It's simply curiosity from my part whether I can get wolfram to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the relevant solutions with the function `prime(x)`, which returns the $x$'th prime number and the syntax `solve {y=prime(x)+30/prime(x)+1} over integers` [(link)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7By%3Dprime(x)%2B30%2Fprime(x)%2B1%7D+over+integers).

Comment: Annoyingly, this just returns the index, $x$, instead of the prime itself, $p_x$ but it's fairly easy to transition between the two.

Comment: Would `solve {y=x+30/x+1; x = prime(p)} over integers` work better?